# Combining two PDF files in C++

Tags: c++, pdf, libharu

In C++ I'm generating a PDF report with [libHaru](http://libharu.org). I'm looking for someway to append two pages from an existing PDF file to the end of my report. Is there any free way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try PoDoFo

http://podofo.sourceforge.net/

You should be able to open both of the `PDFs` as `PDFMemDocuments` using `PDFMemDocument.Load( filename )`.

Then, acquire references to the two pages you want to copy  and add to the end of the document using `InsertPages`, or optionally, remove all but the last two pages of the source document, then call `PDFDocument`.

Append and pass the called document. Hard to say which would be faster or more stable.

Hope that helps,
Troy

Comment: I ended up using the PoDoFo with the InsertPages method. It seems to actually delete all but the needed pages internally. It also crashes on some PDF files, but it works on simple tests and should be OK for my purposes. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) utility `pdf2ps` to convert the PDF files to PostScript, append the PostScript files, and then convert them back to a PDF using `ps2pdf`.

Comment: As much as I love Ghostscript, this solution is really a kludge for anything other than a one-off. That's a really big hammer for such a simple task.